# Inset and boundary

Tags: modeling, selection-tools

When I select a side of a cube I can place an inset but the boundary function does not work.

I've used the hot keys I then <kbd>B</kbd> it toggles the indicator above for boundary on an off but object doesn't change. I've even gone to the inset panel to manually as you can see in the image.

[image: as you can see in the image]

Answer (score 5):

The *'boundary'* option is to determinate if *open edges* (see [the documentation](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/editing/duplicating/inset.html#options)) will be inset or not.

So this option only concerns edges that are on an open border (a cube does not have).

Here is an example using a plane with subdivisions:

[image]

If *'boundary*' is off, the borders won't be inset. If on, they will be.

This is only for borderlines (non closed volume) as if not the inset can't keep quads (or should propagate the modification "too far").